# Incorrect rendering of some parts of texture on Android mobile devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I created texture in Blender and import it to Unity. In Blender everything looks good as well as in the Unity editor and in the game mod in Unity.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOFVs.png)

But after building the apk file and lunching on the mobile devices (I've tried different types), some parts of the texture look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRi5Y.jpg)

This is my first game, so I don't even know how to properly describe what it is, sorry.
Could you please help me solve this problem?

I've tried changing the quality settings in Unity and used different types of shaders and material settings. I use the core 3d mobile template for my game. I didn't use any types of rendering pipelines. I tried to make this texture static.
It looks like I missed something basic, but I don't understand what exactly...
I also noticed a pattern, straight parts of the road look good, but it changes on corners or near corners.

**UPDATE**

I've found the solution to my problem.
The problem was when I added an image to my road in Blender. My road consisted of many faces and I unwraped all the faces to the UV Editing tab in Blender. This was my mistake because I had too many faces. To resolve the problem, I split all the faces into three equal parts and added an image to the road for each part.
Also, note that this problem only affected the mobile version of my game!

Comment: do those bits use a different shader? it could also be the devices dont support erntirely what is in teh shader

Comment: @BugFinder No, the shaders are the same. Also, the straight parts of the road look well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem. The problem was when I added an image to my road in Blender. My road consisted of many faces and I unwraped all the faces to the UV Editing tab in Blender. This was my mistake because I had too many faces. To resolve the problem, I split all the faces into three equal parts and added an image to the road for each part. Also, note that this problem only affected the mobile version of my game!